# Is it possible to directly go to bottom of div generated by ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-repeat which displays the chat messages in a chat.But the oldest chat messages appears first and I have to scroll down to see the latest messages.I want to go to end of ng-repeat after page loads  i.e. to lastest chat and scroll up if required to see old chats as in any other mesaaging app.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <ul class="chat">
                <li ng-repeat="msg in msgListing" ng- class="msg.senderid==senderidvalue ? 'left clearfix sender' : 'right clearfix reciever'">
                        <div class="header">
                            <strong ng-class="msg.senderid==senderidvalue ? 'pull-left primary-font' : 'pull-right primary-font'">
                                <p ng-if="msg.senderid == senderidvalue">{{currentusername}}</p>
                                <p ng-if="msg.senderid != senderidvalue">{{recievername}}</p>
                                </strong> <small ng-class="msg.senderid==senderidvalue ? 'pull-right text-muted' : 'pull-left text-muted'">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>{{msg.senton}}</small>
                        </div>

                        <p class="chat-text">
                            {{msg.messagetext}}
                        </p>    
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[image: Sample Output Image]

Answer (score 2):

while add values use scrollHeight

```js
 
var scroller = document.getElementById("autoscroll");
      scroller.scrollTop = scroller.scrollHeight;
    }, 0, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-repeat with orderBy like here

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
```

you find the docs [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: I want to focus or scroll to last chats automatically...Reversing the array is not helping